# Datastore returns 503 when trying to access from a docker container

Tags: python, docker, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-python

I have a Google Compute Engine instance running Ubuntu 15.10 and docker 1.10.1. When I try to access Google Datastore from gcloud-python on the instance, everything works fine. When I try to access it from inside a docker container based on `python:3.5` I always get a 503 error. Here is the full stacktrace:

```
>>> unit = client.get(key)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/client.py", line 262, in get
    deferred=deferred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/client.py", line 303, in get_multi
    transaction_id=transaction and transaction.id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/client.py", line 136, in _extended_lookup
    transaction_id=transaction_id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/connection.py", line 200, in lookup
    _datastore_pb2.LookupResponse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/connection.py", line 118, in _rpc
    data=request_pb.SerializeToString())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcloud/datastore/connection.py", line 95, in _request
    raise make_exception(headers, content, use_json=False)
gcloud.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Backend Error
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was resolved by enabling the "Google Cloud Datastore API (v1beta2)". This is not to be confused with the "Google Cloud Datastore API". To do so, you can go to the API Manager overview, search for "datastore" select "Google Cloud Datastore API (v1beta2)" then click the "enable" button.